# Linear cost traveling salesman heuristic

Tags: global-optimization

I have a sequence of points $y_1,\ldots,y_n\in \mathbb{R}^3$  and want to approximately minimise 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}|y_{\pi(i)}-y_{\pi(i+1)}|
$$
by choosing a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.
I have a budget of $\mathcal{O}(n\log(n)^p)$ for some $p\in\mathbb{N}$. What would be the best heuristic for this endeavour?

Comment: You can't minimize a single number. What are you permitting to vary?

Comment: Of course you are right. Forgot to mention the permutation.